# Information needed with Time Series Data

Tags: r, time-series

My Time Series Data, doesn't have a proper trend (neither upwards nor downwards). Its more of like a seasonal component, goes ups & downs for a span of 10 years. Which method/process we should apply here, or is there any way out from it ?

I am trying it in R Studio, tried to decompose the data which shows clearly the trend, more of like a parabola.

Comment: What is the question you are asking of the data? That's where you should start any data analysis.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for. What is the goal for your analysis?

Comment: Ok i  have a stock data & i want to do some time series forecasting on it, now after decomposing the data i could see the trend has both up & downward stream. Now my question is how to deal with in this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

stock data (price ) is usually not very predictable as it is often driven by emotion ... normally the best prediction is the last value ( random-walk model )